# ASP.NET add Link to file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add to table cell in asp table link to file, which is in application folder and is a word document (.docx). How can I add this link here?

```
...
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell> here I want to add link to file in application folder Content/Files/document.docx </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about use link element? `<a href="Content/Files/document.docx">document</a>`.

If app folder is not accessible directly you have to create handler to provide content of this file and use the [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method to properly locate the file:

`Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/document.docx")`